# How to print colored text using a black and white printer?

Tags: printing, cups, printer

I printed a PDF containing colored text using `lp file.pdf`. I expected the text to show up in grey or black, but it was not printed at all.

Is this expected behaviour? Can I change a setting somewhere to handle color in some sensible manner?

My printer is an OKI 4100.

Comment: No, that isn't expected behavior. Sounds like a general issue with your printer. Does printing a black and white page work? I really doubt this would have anything to do with color.

Comment: Please edit question with your printer model and the installed driver you are using. Ideas to debug: Convert to Postscript with `pdf2ps` and `xpdf` printing dialog (try both), try if it prints then. Possibly it's also a colorspace issue (PDF supports several colorspaces), so other PDFs with color may print correctly.

Comment: Most printer drivers have options to convert colour to "black and white" or "grey scale". I don't know where this would be set using `lp` or your specific printer, but lighter colours could come out white with the "black and white" setting.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the wrong driver. There is no driver for the B4100 but the driver for the Laserjet 1100 is [known to work](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20070309085214/http://www.linuxprinting.org:80/show_printer.cgi?recnum=Okidata-B4100). For some reason I was using the Laserjet *4* driver instead.